# Why is CSS position attribute affecting a rotation animation?

Tags: css, animation, css-position, css-animations

I'm working on a website (that I *didn't* design, someone else gave me the HTML/CSS) as a developer and We've got a nice spinner animation for async loading components. It's forever-spinning animation is defined by this CSS rule:

`animation: spinning 1s infinite linear;` (it has also vendor prefix versions but it's irrelevant).

The `spinning` animation is defined as:

```
@keyframes spinning { 
    0% { transform: rotate(0); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

Our designer has put a `position: absolute !important` attribute to the spinning element. I was trying to position it inside some other element and I've thought that attribute was irrelevant. As soon as I removed `position: absolute`, the spinner stopped spinning. When I added it again, spinner started spinning again.

I've tried other `position` values too, it seems that `absolute` and `fixed` are working okay (in regards to spinning animation) while `relative` and `static` cause the animation to stop.

Why would CSS position attribute affect a spinner animation?

Here is a snippet reproducing the problem:

```css
@keyframes spinning { 
    0% { transform: rotate(0); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
#first{
  position: absolute;
}
#second{
  position: relative; /* or don't specify it at all */
}
```

```html
<div style='background:yellow;width:400px;height:100px;'>
  <span id='first' style='animation:spinning 1s infinite linear'>hello</span>
</div>
<div style='background:lime;width:400px;height:100px;'>
  <span id='second' style='animation:spinning 1s infinite linear'>hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've no clue why that's happening, but you can also place elements with an absolute position into parental elements, using `position:relative`in those parents.

Comment: @Ash I wish I could but it's a big enterprise project with many components over and there so it's practically impossible. It's even extremely hard to provide a SSCCE, as even creating one may take hours. I am looking for any well-known clues about why this would happen, if it's a known issue by the community.

Comment: I think you should check the **spinning** keyframe. 
It may give you the answer based on the html structure

Comment: @ToanLu I'd love to, but how do I do that? :) (I'm really new to CSS animations, so excuse my lack of knowledge about the context)

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: you can check out this article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/ 
Then you can look for the keyframe **spinning** in your CSS files (it's some where in your CSS files)
It may be caused by the styles in this keyframe, it may changes position (top, right, bottom, left) and the rotate degree. 
If possible, you can post the keyframe of the animation here, so we can inspect

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought I was clear on why I couldn't put an SSCCE in the comments above.

Comment: Sure, but it's down to you to **recreate** the problem with minimal code. You might even find the problem. If you can't provide the code, how can we diagnose it. Help us help you.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm trying, but it's a bit messed up. I've asked it so maybe there was an answer like "yeah, you need to specifiy position to absolute for animation to work because [...]" kind of answer (just made it up, but you get the idea). anyway, I'll try to create it now.

Comment: @Paulie_D okay you were right, it took shorter time than I've expected, please see my updated question below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because a `span` is an `inline-element` by default and so is not affected by `transforms`.

Setting the position to absolute imparts a block formatting to the span.

Just add `display:inline-block`:

```css
@keyframes spinning {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
div.one {
  background: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
div.two {
  background: lime;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
#first {
  position: absolute;
  animation: spinning 1s infinite linear
}
#second {
  position: relative;
  /* or don't specify it at all */
  animation: spinning 1s infinite linear;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <span id='first'>hello</span>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <span id='second'>hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know inline elements weren't affected by transforms. Now it makes sense.